# Launching youtube or Netflix application from iOS app by passing some credential details

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I want to develop an enterprise application which have an entertainment feature. Basically I want to redirect to youtube or Netflix app with some login credentials or token. Youtube or Netflix app should use these credentials or token for authentication and allow the user to access the contents. Please let me know this is possible ? If yes how?

Answer (score 0):

**YouTube**

You can embed youtube videos in iOS app using below YouTube player pod :

```
pod "YoutubePlayer-in-WKWebView", "~> 0.2.0"
```

For more information refer YouTube official [website](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper)

**Netflix**

and i think Netflix is not provided any sdk or API's and open source to access videos for iOS Swift.

You can check other languages open source for NetFlix on github [here](https://github.com/Netflix?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=&type=&language=)